# Delays acquiring worker threads in an ASP .Net Core 3.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Our application is experiencing delays when acquiring worker/pool threads in an ASP .Net Core 3.0 project.

In newer language, this means effectively when spawning a Task, the amount of time between the Task.Start() command and the first line of code *in* the tasks executing.  Essentially the amount of time the thread pool management process takes to create the thread.

Some factors to bear in mind:

1. At the time of asking, there are 600+ free worker/pool threads.
2. The code doing this is in a .Net Framework 4.7.2 application being referenced by an ASP .Net Core 3.0 host application.
3. There isn't *always* a delay, but when there is, all items requesting worker threads from that same 4.7.2 component are subject to it.  Times vary, but I've seem 300ms.
4. The application is not under heavy load at the time, with memory usage and CPU utilization at normal levels.
5. The code requesting the worker/pool thread is doing it in a .Net 1.1 style:

```
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MethodName, e);
```

6. We are issuing this command in void Main in Program.cs:

```
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 1000);
```

Comment: Your post suggests you expect the queueing operation to be effectively synchronous? Or at least the acquisition of the thread/

Comment: What's a "worker thread" to you? What do you mean by "delay when acquiring worker threads"? Note the ideal number of threads is 1 per core + (async/hardware/IO threads). Adding more threads will not make your machine faster (it's the contrary since the system needs to switch over, etc.)

Comment: @SimonMourier the worker threads are the thread pool threads, i.e. those set in the code I posted.  Read here for background info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @SimonMourier for the same reason one might care how much memory your application is using, or how much CPU time it utilises.    You might not care, but for an unattended, long-running server application running many processes it is not beyond reasonable doubt that a bug might occur which causes a repeated process which leaks memory, or spawns Tasks which don't exit, causing a leak of pool threads.

Comment: @SimonMourier I also think you've fundamentally misunderstood the question; you seem to be thinking I'm asking about the performance of *running* threads.   This is not the case and the question is pretty clear:  I am querying why the scheduling of threads on the threadpool is subject to such an inordinate delay in *this particular instance* - and have made an effort to describe this.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt - Indeed I didn't understand, hence my questions. Now you've edited it it's more clear what you mean by "acquire". What stays identical is why do you create so many threads in the pool (hence my remark about you not known what a thread pool is). In general, you shouldn't change that, as tasks that go in the pool should be reasonable quick. Or it means tasks you push take too long ("too long" is to be defined) in the pool (and that's another problem, maybe the root problem).

Comment: you do realize that `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` not working instant - it`s just a guide for Thread Poll to create new Thread faster - but still not instant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use ThreadPool for what it's not supposed to be used. This is what official [Silverlight docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/0ka9477y(v=vs.95)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) say, which is most likely applicable to .Net Framework 4 as well:

> When Not to Use Thread Pool Threads
>
> In the following scenarios, it is appropriate to create and manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads:
>
> 1. You need to start a number of threads in a very short time, to execute tasks that last a second or more. As part of its thread management strategy, the thread pool delays before creating threads. Therefore, when a number of tasks are queued in a short period of time, there can be a significant delay before all the tasks are started.

Comment: But this happens only on this Asp.Net Core 3 app.  We've had the same code inside a .Net Framework host app for years without this problem.  In this situation the call for new threads wasn't particularly high either so the delay is not easily explainable.